# How use EF on SqlConnection object

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, sqlconnection

I have an old winforms project which uses localDB and ADO.NET SqlConnection. Now I have created a new database (not local), which I use Entity Framework to connect to. When I use the new EF-database on my SqlConnection I get the error that says SqlConnection does not support the metadata from my new connectionstring.

Is it correct that SqlConnection needs a localDB? How can I do so that the SqlConnection can connect to my new database?

//Martin

Comment: You should be a little bit more specific and probably the problem is not related to EF but is related to the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

An Entity framework connection string contains a meta data element that points to the location of the entity framework model:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
         Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
         multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

A Sql connection string looks something like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

If your application uses an SQLConnection then you must connect to the database with a connection string that has the structure of a SQLConnection string.